# Don't Understand Bundler Interaction with Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake, bundler, rubymine

I thought I understood how Bundler works with gems, but after something that recently happened, I am not sure I have it right.

I am developing an Rails application. To start off (and just so I would get familiar with the Rails environment which I haven't worked in before), I did not use an IDE. But, because I'm missing out on some of the advantages of an IDE, I just started using RubyMine. As part of the RubyMine setup, it asked to update all my gems for my existing project.

After that, I could not run "rake [anything]". Every time I did, I received an error of:

> You have already activated rake 0.9.3.beta.1, but your Gemfile
>   requires rake 0.9.2.2. Using bundle exec may solve this.

I was okay updating to the next version of rake - that wasn't a problem - but I don't understand what happened in the first place. What happened that I "activated" a newer version of rake. Ultimately, I ended up solving the problem by putting

```
gem 'rake', '0.9.3.beta.1'
```

in my Gemfile and running

```
bundle update rake
```

But, I'm still not sure what happened here. If I was using 9.2.2 before, why did it all of a sudden blow up like that and how can I prevent that in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really consider installing and using **[RVM](https://rvm.io/)** or **[Rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)** to manage your ruby versions and gemsets. If you go the Rbenv way, the **[rbenv-gemset](https://github.com/jamis/rbenv-gemset)** plugin can be used to manage gemsets similar to how RVM natively does.

> You have already activated rake 0.9.3.beta.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2.2. Using bundle exec may solve this.

At some point between your last `bundle` execution and installing/configuring/running RubyMine you must have installed `rake 0.9.3.beta.1`. Because you're not managing your gems through gemsets like RVM or Rbenv will do for you, the default version of Rake became `0.9.3.beta.1` instead of the version installed by bundler, `0.9.2.2`.

The above error suggests your `Gemfile` had something like

```
gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'
```

which does not allow the version of rake being used to be anything but `0.9.2.2`.

If you do in fact have `0.9.2.2` on your system in addition to the `0.9.3.beta.1` and your `Gemfile` is configured for `0.9.2.2`, instead of running

```
rake some:task
```

you can run

```
bundle exec rake some:task
```

and bundler will run `some:task` through the `0.9.2.2` version of rake. Running tasks related to gems found in a `Gemfile` through bundleer with `bundle exec ...`  is considered good practice regardless of using RVM or Rbenv.

You can read about `bundle exec` **[here](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html)**.

Comment: I'll look into RVM. But...to ask about your response...I figured my Gemfile had that line in it - but it didn't. That's what's confusing me. (BUT...my Gemfile.lock had =0.9.2.2 in it - I just don't know how that got there.)

Comment: If it was in `Gemfile.lock` and not explicitly set in your `Gemfile`, it was specified as a dependency of one of the many gems that **are** in your `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Rubymine, you should configure it to run rake tasks with `bundle exec`.

Go to:
*Run -> Edit Configurations -> Defaults -> Rake -> Bundler tab* and check "Run the script in context of the bundle (**bundle exec**)"

Delete all tasks already created and the default will apply the next time you create them again. You can also configure individually each task created.