# How do I use bundle exec rake on RubyMine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, rubymine

i found this post in stack overflow 
[rubymine error: You have already activated rake 10.0.3, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.6. Using bundle exec may solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712009/rubymine-error-you-have-already-activated-rake-10-0-3-but-your-gemfile-require)

that offesr two possible solutions:

- ignoring global gem path in the project settings
- uninstalling the problematic gem

So far none of these solutions worked for me: I tried ignoring the global gem path, but I keep getting the same error message. With regards to uninstalling the gem, well, that's not possible as I have other projects depending on the newer rake version, which I don't want to mess up with.

What would be a way to force RubyMine into using bundle exec before rake tasks?

Comment: running `bundle update` can sometimes resolve this.  Another simple way is to remove `rake 10.0.3` from a terminal window, `gem uninstall rake` and then pick `10.0.3` from the list you are presented.

Comment: The uninstall worked, thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Go to <kbd>Run</kbd> -> <kbd>Edit Configurations</kbd>, select the BUNDLER tab, and click the checkbox "Run the script in context of the bundle (bundle exec)"

Comment: Is there a way to set it as checked by default?

Comment: After doing this, I still don't see `bundle exec` in the command arguments.

Comment: @lulalala It does not show it there, but if you check the console you will see it using the ``bundle exec``

Comment: @Renews hmm I don't see it there in the log either. Lemme double check tmr.

Comment: There is a way to set default. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13839851/481023